# MySQL - WHERE x IN ( column)

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried something out. Here is a simple example in SQL Fiddle: [Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8cc0a9/1)

There is a column someNumbers (comma-seperated numbers) and I tried to get all the rows where this column contains a specific number. Problem is, the result only contains rows where someNumbers starts with the specific number.

The query `SELECT * FROM myTable where 2 in ( someNumbers )` only returns the row with id 2 and not the row with id 1.

Any suggestions? Thank you all.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results *in the question, in a tabular format*.  You have enough rep that you should know how to do this.

Comment: There is a SQL Fiddle example but I update the question.

Comment: The `IN` operator doesn't work like that, your `someNumbers ` column is just a single value and not a real list

Comment: @xander is there a solution to get the desired rows? Problem with LIKE "%2% is that it also returns the row with 22.

Comment: storing multiple values in one column is violation of first normal form

Comment: @Elham Kohestani: Sometimes you are dealing with legacy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are storing data in the wrong format!  You should not be storing multiple values in a single string column.  You should not be storing numbers as strings.  Instead, you should have a junction table with one row per `id` and per `number`.

Sometimes, you just have no choice, because someone else created a really poorly designed database.  For these situations, MySQL has the function `find_in_set()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable 
WHERE find_in_set(2, someNumbers ) > 0;
```

The right solution, however, is to fix the data model.

Answer (score 4):

While Gordon's answer is a good one, here is a way to do this with `like`

```
SELECT * FROM myTable where someNumbers like '2,%' or someNumbers like '%,2,%' or someNumbers like '%,2'
```

The first `like` checks if your array starts with the number you are looking for (2). The second one checks if 2 is within the array and the last `like` tests for appearance at the end.

Note that the commas are essential here, because something like `'%2%'` would also match `...,123,...`

EDIT: As suggested by the OP it may happen that only a single value is present in the row. Consequently, the query must check this case by doing `... someNumbers = '2'`

Comment: don't forget the possible case where only one Number is stored in the column .... AND someNumbers='2'

Comment: This is a good example of dealing with legacy stuff. Just to mention: although this will work it will be extremely inefficient as no index will be used for a query like this. If you are building some production-level feature on this you should consider normalizing the structure.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this query :

```
    SELECT * FROM myTable where someNumbers like '%2%'
```

It will select every entry where someNumbers contains '2'

Comment: Yes, but it returns also rows with e.g. 22.So it should be something like: WHERE someNumbers = '2' or someNumbers LIKE '2,%' or someNumbers like '%,2' or someNumbers LIKE '%,2,%' .... that's not very elegant ;-)

Comment: Yes it was just to give you the idea but there are few other cases to consider indeed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from table_name where coloumn_name IN(value,value,value)
```

you can use it

Comment: Correct query but the part (value,value,value) is the value of a column. That's the problem.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.